# How to solve this inequality , when there is a irrational power?

Tags: inequality

$$\frac{(x-2)(x-3)^\sqrt{2}}{(x+1)}>0$$

I'm confused with $(x-3)^\sqrt{2}$ factor.

When $x>3$ it is positive.

When  $x=3$ this inequality does not hold.

When $x<3$, I am confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we have the factor$$(x-3)^{\sqrt{2}}$$ it must be $$x>3$$ then it is $$(x-3)^{\sqrt{2}}$$ a real number.

Comment: So , sir it is never a negative when $x \geq 3$ ?

Comment: No, it must be $x>3$ since the inequality is strict.

Comment: $0$ is not greater than zero, so $x=3$ is not a solution.

Comment: So numbers like $(-2)^\sqrt{3}$ are complex numbers ?

Answer (score 9):

You don't have to worry about $x < 3$ because it is not in the domain. Irrational powers are not defined when the base is negative.

You might remember that for an irrational number $a$, by definition the exponentiation function with exponent $a$ is defined by
$$t^a = e^{a \ln(t)}
$$
and the domain of that function is the positive axis $t > 0$.

So for your function, the domain is $x > 3$.

Comment: $$x=1/2$$ is not defined for instance.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the clash of variables in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: For $x<3$, $(x-3)^{\sqrt 2}$ is not defined, so you must impose the condition $x\ge 3$ from the start. Aftwerwards you may proceed as you did.